# How to passing an Object from HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

How to convert html data attribute into JavaScript Object?
I try to use JSON.parse() but it got some error
There is result of my String Data

```
{
  _id: 5f71ea3362749a305427a012,
  name: 'House With Beauty Backyard',
  __v: 0
}
```

When i use JSON.parse() it return error

```
VM5246:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 4
```

My EJS Code

```
<a href="javascript:void()" data-category="<%= category[i] %>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

My JS Code

```
<script>
    $('#dataTable .btn-update').on('click', function () {
        let dataString = $(this).data('category');
        console.log(dataString);
        let dataJson = JSON.parse(dataString);
        console.log(dataJson);
        $('#update-modal').modal('show');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a more accurate example of the problem, and the initial state of the page. The code in the first example is an object, not a string, and it's also not a valid object as the GUID needs to be wrapped in quotes. In addition, you'd need to call `JSON.stringify()` on it to turn it in to JSON, not `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify`. Try this code:

```
let dataJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataString));
console.log(dataJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires quotes ("") for keys and string values.

This would be your "String Data" with valid form:

```
{
  "_id": "5f71ea3362749a305427a012",
  "name": "House With Beauty Backyard",
  "__v": 0
}
```

The parsing error will disappear, if you change your data format to valid JSON.(RFC 8259)

Here you can find out more about JSON:
https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc8259.pdf